# What is GDPR in the SO Help Desk?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, help-center

I went to submit a request in the [SO for teams help desk](https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/26) and saw on the product dropdown list:

- Stack Overflow for Teams, Free
- Stack Overflow for Teams, Basic
- Stack Overflow for Teams, Business
- Stack Overflow for Teams, Enterprise
- Stack Overflow Talent
- GDPR

I was unsure what GDPR was, so I did some research:

- I conducted a [search on SO teams help that yielded no results](https://stackoverflow.help/en/?q=gpdr)
- I tried a search on SO meta but there were no results
- Finally, I DuckDuckGoed it, but I didn't get anything useful

What is GDPR and why is it so unclear as to what it is?

Comment: *"Finally, I DuckDuckGoed it, but I didn't get anything useful"* - I find that impossible to believe

Comment: GDPR is the "General Data Protection Regulation" is a law on data protection in the EU. [Relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). It's not GPDR. Double check and it should be spelled with a D before the P.

Comment: @OlegValter Sure, but the reason they asked the question is because they were searching for the wrong initialism and couldn't find it.

Comment: @khelwood - I sincerely [hope not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGZb.png) :) but you may be right, come to think of it, I overlooked the search part (which included `q=gpdr`) - if that's the case, agreed, I'd leave the typo be

Comment: @khelwood That's correct.

Comment: @OlegValter I said "DuckDuckGoed it", not "Googled it"...

Comment: [GPDR is a quite common misspelling/typo](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=GPDR) (but not necessarily in this case). It is usually clear from the context it is in.

Comment: @Anonymous - if you think I did not notice, you are wrong :) Here goes [DDG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaBct.png) for ya

Comment: @OlegValter I thought that the correct spelling was wrong, so I used quotes...

Comment: @Anonymous - don't get me wrong, I do not want to ridicule the attempt you made - just that, well, did it not occur to you to double-check after the search yielded something you think is irrelevant (or nothing at all)? :) I assume there is no typo in the dropdown list of the help desk page, right?

Comment: @OlegValter Yes, there isn't a typo in the actual page, just the search I conducted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) (General Data Protection Regulation) is a law on data protection and privacy, effective in the EU. It also adresses the transfer of personal data outside the EU.

Many people who use Stack Overflow live in the EU, so Stack Overflow has to follow these laws. For instance, if the [emails of members were leaked <sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322154/500111), the legal team *may* have to notify the relevant authorities of the data leakage within 72 hours.

This is why there is an entry for GDPR in the help desk for Teams. So that users can ask questions about data privacy in Teams.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In that specific case, the legal team said that no personal data was leaked, and that there were new processes in place to prevent something like that again, so no data breach was reported.</sub>

Comment: This really does not answer the question as asked... I have no idea what OP mean "GPDR" ... possibly they wanted to report a bug (in some trolling way). Maybe if you edit the question post with an image it could be a bit more clear... or just edit the question with GDRP instead of GPDR...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That seems to be counter to "Assume good faith"..